# A Poisson structure induced by double Poisson bracket

Tags: rt.representation-theory, noncommutative-geometry, poisson-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\Sym{Sym}$Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero. In Van den Bergh's paper [Double Poisson algebras](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2008-360-11/S0002-9947-08-04518-2/), it is shown that a double Poisson bracket on an unital associative algebra $A$ induces a Poisson structure on the $n$-dimensional representation space of $A$.

Let $A=k[t]$. There is a double Poisson bracket given by
$$\{\{t,\,t\}\}=t^2\otimes t-t\otimes t^2\,.$$
Moreover, the $n$-dimensional representation space of $k[t]$ can be identified with $M_n(k)$, the space of $n\times n$ matrices. And the ring of functions is $\Sym (M^\ast_n(k))$. Explicitly, the induced Poisson structure is given by
$$[E^\ast_{ij},\,E^\ast_{kl}]\,=\,\sum_r E^\ast_{kr}E^\ast_{rj}E^\ast_{il}-E^\ast_{kj}E^\ast_{ir}E^\ast_{rl}\,.$$
One can identify $M^\ast_n(k)$ with $M_n(k)$ via the trace pairing. Hence this is also a Poisson structure on $\Sym (M_n(k))$.

My question is that are there any interpretations of this Poisson bracket on $\Sym (M^\ast_n(k))$ (or $\Sym (M_n(k))$)? Thanks in advance.